# Module not found: how can i solve it

Tags: reactjs

hey i was watching the youtube video in it he was trying the new way of linking for hime it works and for me it shows the error video link :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khJlrj3Y6Ls time stamps are from 12:00 to 13:29   and the folder structure is also the same 
error showing is :

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './Component' in 'C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Desktop\react learn\covid-19\src'
```

and the app.js is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Cards,Charts,CountryPicker} from './Component';
class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
<div>
<h1>here is me   the app</h1>  
</div>
);
}}
export default App;
```

index.js in component folder is

```
export {default as Cards } from './Cards/Cards';
export {default as Charts } from './Charts/Charts';
export {default as CountryPicker } from './CountryPicker/CountryPicker';
```

and i have checked tons of time myself but couldn t do something 
folder structure is :https://ibb.co/vXy4ssf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled your folder name. You should import your components from `'./Components'` instead of `'./Component'`